# Redux form - own value in Field with type radio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to put some text in to the radio field (with Redux form).

I have fields like this:

```
<Field
  name={some.name1}
  value={'text1'}
  component={renderRadioElement}
  type="radio"
/>

<Field
  name={some.name2}
  value={'text2'}
  component={renderRadioElement}
  type="radio"
/>

...
```

Everything works correctly until the **first value change**.

If I want to change the value several times: **state -> form -> ... -> values -> some** does not update values.

**My question is** - how to correctly enter a text value into a radio field?

Comment: I dont understand. when you say text on a radio button what do you mean, could you show me in html what you want

Comment: Just something else then "on" value... for example "some text 1".

Comment: I want to have this value in my state -> form -> formName -> some -> name1

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your comment you have a value on your component state where youve decleared the form and you wnat to pass in that value to your field.
If thats it what you want to do is dispatch the value to the redux-form store.
To do that in your class you are receiving a prop which is change. injected by redux-form. what you want to do is use that function to set the value

```
const { change } = this.props;
change('some.name2', this.state.yourValue)
```

hope it helps